# Вызов другого VBScript из Visual Basic

Tags: visual-basic, exe, vbscript

Товарищи программисты!

Я ничего не понимаю в VB, но у меня острая нужда сделать VBScript, который будет состоять из запуска другого VBScript, хранящегося в той же директории. Скрипт, который надо запустить у меня готов, а вот как его запустить - это вопрос.

По сути пользователь запускает этот скрипт, а тот в свою очередь запускает другой, более объёмный.

*Собственно помощь состоит в том, чтобы написать эти пару строк VB кода, которые запустят файл "run.vbs".*

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

PS: Важное замечание! **Вызов командной строки или исполнение .bat/.cmd файлов исключены.**

Comment: WScript.Shell метод Run

Comment: @Daemon-5 получается WScript.Shell.Run("run.vbs")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim WshShell
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "run.vbs", ,true
```

Это сработало!